# my sqlite3 DB copies over with 0 bytes for size

Tags: ios, sqlite, xamarin

My DB is not getting copied over!

Here is what I am doing:

Create a new sqllite3 db from terminal:

```
sqlite> create table myTable (id integer primary key, name text);
sqlite> insert into myTable (name) values ('john');
sqlite> select * from myTable;
1|john
```

This creates a db in this path: users/John/iosApp.db with a size of 2kb

Then I copy that db to my xamarin project and set it buildAction to
    'content'

I go to the path of the project and I mark the db and ensure that its size is still 2kb...

then I run the app and I set a breaking point after the second line:

```
string pathToDatabase = "iosApp.db";
userPath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), pathToDatabase);
```

it gives me this path: "/Users/John/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0.3/Applications/6347705D-033A-44EA-91DF-4B5F31A2ED31/Documents/iosApp.db"

when I navigate to that path, behold... the db size is zero byte!

I have tried all the following:

- Clean All in the project
- Rebuild All
- removed the 'debug' folder from the project
- restarted Xamarin
- and even restart the machine

But still the same behavior, what else should I try?

my sdk version is attached[image]

Comment: Did you quit the SQLite tool after creating and populating the database (and before copying the file)? If not, the SQLite tool may not have flushed all the data to disk, meaning your copy might not be a valid database file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you add a file to your project as "Content" it is copied as part of your application bundle.  It is NOT automatically copied to the "Documents" folder - you have to do that explicitly.

You should be able to open the file and read it (files in the app bundle are not writable) using the path "iosApp.db" since that is relative to the root of the app bundle.  You can open a read-only SQLite connection using that path, or you can use File IO to copy the file from the app bundle to one of the Special Folders, where it will be writable.